# Is there a single word that means 'more information on a user'

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm a programmer and I'm looking for a single word that works for the following scenario:

- I have a list of basic information about people, I call this list the 'user repository'.
- I need a word for "to view and change more detailed information about a person". I've thought of using words like refine and elaborate, but they don't seem to quite fit the idea that the data can be viewed and changed.

Comment: "user database" may be used. But thats not a single word again. In that case, how did u think of using refine and elaborate?

Comment: I thought of them because I was trying to think of how I would describe something in more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you'll find a single word that does quite what you want, but you may be able to contrast **user details** with a **user profile** or **user summary** held in the repository.  I guess that you can see the details of multiple users at a time when viewing the repository.  Whatever you use you'll probably be best off with a phrase for the detailed information, paired with "view" or "edit" as necessary.

You may find more help at [UX](https://ux.stackexchange.com/), for example they have questions like [User Profile, My Account, or just Settings?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/1328/user-profile-my-account-or-just-settings) suggesting that your question may be on topic there.

Answer (score 0):

Still there is no single word but in some extent "Detailed" and "Non-Detailed"  will work . I am not sure this will substitute your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

'update' or 'modify' are used to describe viewing and changing the user profile.